# Killing and reading the reply from Process performing Ping Comand

Tags: java

I'm creating a ping bot and have some problems reading data and kill a process when I make a infinite (-t) ping. The program dose what it is suppose to do. But it is still processing my pings in the background even when i close the program if the ping haven't completed.

This is the calculating part of an class that create a new window with a text area. It takes in the IP, Count of pings and Size.

```
if (countInput.equals("-1")){
      countInput = "-t ";
  } else {
      countInput = "-n " + countInput;
  }

  String pingCmd = "ping " + countInput + " -l " + sizeInput + " " + ipInput;

  Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
      try {
          Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
          Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);

          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
          String inputLine;
          while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
              final String outputLine = inputLine;
              Platform.runLater(() -> textArea.appendText(outputLine + "\n"));
          }
          in.close();
      } catch (IOException event) {
          System.out.println(event);
      }
  });
  thread.start();
}
```

I have tried to kill the Process and the Runtime with no luck.
I managed to add a button to the screen that i want to kill the ping command and return the result so i can print it to the Text-Area (like Ctrl-C in cmd).

Please tell me if you need any more of the program.

EDIT: What i have done:

- I have tried to execute a thread/Runtime/Process killing when the stage is closed, also tried in a finally stage on the while loop. Nothing seemed to stop the ping it self.
- I tried to create a BufferedWriter to the OutputStream() on the process and tried to send a "Ctrl-c"/killing command to the Cmd it self, with no luck.

So the best thing would be to modify the program to have a method for killing the CMD Process and return the end value (similar to use Ctrl-c in a CMD application ping), and be able to post that result in the text area.

Comment: I don't see any killing happening in your code.

Comment: No i reverted it to the last working before i started handling the killing process. Now i wonder how to handle it.

Comment: Take a look at methdos available on `Process` class, there should be one that's appropriate for you.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, thank you. Updated the post and have already tried that with no luck.

Comment: Does that mean that `destroyForcibly()` doesn't work on ping process? How is this manifested?

Comment: Did any of that help or is this a dead question now?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answers, and im so sorry i have hade os much to do att work so haven't have time to test :(

Though i dont think that really helps with my other problems, that is sending  a "Ctrl+C" command to the process and listen to the response, and then posting it to the textArea.

That might be able to do if i set up a BufferedWriter along with the reader?